# Wie unterscheiden sich "Menschenmasse," "Gedränge," und "Andrang"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Ich suche nach der besten Übersetzung der englischen Phrase "Huge crowds of people." Der Kontext sind die sehr vielen Besucher, die in den USA wegen der am 21. stattfindenen Sonnenfinsternis erwartet werden.

Comment: Es gibt noch andere Wörter, die hier passen würden. Es kommt auf die Art von Text an, wo du das verwenden willst. Was ist das für ein Text bei dir?

Comment: Ich schreibe eine Email an einen Freund.

Answer (score 2):

'Andrang' würde man eher bei einem Ereignis verwenden, zu dem es einen Zugang gibt, oder dessen Kapazitäten irgendwie begrenzt sind.

'Gedränge' fokussiert darauf, dass es eng ist. Das kann aber natürlich eine passende Verbildlichung sein, um darzustellen, dass sehr viele Leute da sind.

'Menschenmasse(n)' oder 'Menschenmenge' scheint mir die wörtlichste Übersetzung von "huge crowd" zu sein.

Answer (score 2):

"Andrang" sagt aus, wieviele Leute *hinein wollen*. Hier handelt es sich um Menschen, die "herandrängen". Das hört sich aber so an, als ob man sich zur Sonnenfinsternis irgendwo anstellen müsste, passt daher nicht.

"Gedränge" fokussiert darauf, wieviele *schon drin sind*. Diese Menschen drängen sich *in* der Veranstaltung. Passt auch nicht richtig für eine Sonnenfinsternis, die ja nicht in geschlossenen Räumen stattfindet.

Wenn der Text vorher erklärt, dass die Sonnenfinsternis am 21. August nur in einem sehr begrenzten Raum tatsächlich sichtbar sein wird und darauf fokussieren möchte, dass sich in diesem Streifen sehr große Menschenmengen "drängen", die Hotels ausgebucht sind usw., *könnte* man möglicherweise einen Kontext herstellen, in dem auch "Andrang" und "Gedränge" funktionieren. Den Kontext hast du aber leider nicht mitgeliefert.

Und "Menschenmassen" sind einfach große Mengen von Menschen. Für "huge crowds of people" von den dreien sicher die beste Übersetzung. Aber sicher auch nicht die einzige:

- Menschenmenge
- Besuchermasse
- Horden von Besuchern
- Publikumsmassen (eine Nebenbedeutung von "crowd")
- Zuschauermassen (s.o.)
- Volksauflauf

Answer (score 1):

> Wegen der totalen Sonnenfinsternis erwarten viele Orte einen **Besucheransturm**. *(visitors rushing in)*
>
> Fluggesellschaften verzeichneten einen hohen **Andrang** auf Flüge durch den Bereich der Finsternis. *(run)*
>
> Die **Menge** kennt nur eine Blickrichtung: Nach oben. *(crowd)*
>
> Die totale Sonnenfinsternis war ein Spektakel für **die Massen**. *(the masses)*
>
> Das größte **Gedränge** gab es aber auf den Autobahnen. *(throng)*

Answer (score 0):

*Menschenmasse* bezeichnet eine große Ansammlung von Menschen.

*Gedränge* beschreibt die Situation in einer Menschenmasse.

*Andrang* bezeichnet die Bewegung einer Menschenmasse in Richtung auf ein Ziel.